# net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID in Google Chrome and Edge

Tags: javascript, angular, google-chrome

I use **google chrome** and **edge** as browser .In my angular project when I want to show image I get the following error :

```
net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID
```

[image]
**NOTE**: I did not get this error in **firefox**.

**NOTE**: This error happens **in production** mode.**in development** it works great.

**NOTE**: I open the website in the other computer, but this error exist.

I search a lot , but did not find any solution.